# Google map still not showing in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that when run in debug mode, shows Google map fine. But when run in release mode (by clicking very bottom left menu icon and selecting Build variants -> Release) does not display the map. Have hard-coded API key into manifest.xml and google_maps_api.xml as recommended by others in related posts but still doesn't work. Get zillions of error messages when attempting to run release version. Here is a sample:

```
04-23 13:31:34.562  10519-10612/? E/b? Authentication failed on the server.
04-23 13:31:34.563  10519-10612/? E/Google Maps Android API? Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-23 13:31:34.568  10519-10612/? E/Google Maps Android API? In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: AIzaSyDRtOnaTU1Jc-zxuirnbyNojZn9uasd7eE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 1D:9A:59:E7:67:94:D0:38:80:96:35:E9:A8:90:18:17:3C:56:19:4D;owner.example.com.locator
04-23 13:31:35.361      263-339/? E/Vold? Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.apalon.weatherlive.free/cache/
04-23 13:31:35.364      263-339/? E/Vold? Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.apalon.weatherlive.free/cache/
04-23 13:31:35.366      263-339/? E/Vold? Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.apalon.weatherlive.free/cache/
04-23 13:31:35.572  10746-10746/? E/helpmorelib#? init
04-23 13:31:35.583  10746-10746/? A/Adjust? PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this setting only for the build that you want to publish. Set the environment to `sandbox` if you want to test your app!
04-23 13:31:35.720  10746-10787/? E/ActivityThread? Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
04-23 13:31:35.832    2119-2137/? E/DataBuffer? Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@2a363d32)
04-23 13:31:35.832    2119-2137/? E/DataBuffer? Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@6697a83)
04-23 13:31:35.832    2119-2137/? E/DataBuffer? Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@228f4400)
04-23 13:31:35.833    2119-2137/? E/DataBuffer? Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@35b82439)
04-23 13:31:35.833    2119-2137/? E/DataBuffer? Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@3786fa7e)
04-23 13:31:35.915      263-339/? E/Vold? Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.apalon.weatherlive.free/cache/
04-23 13:31:35.957      263-339/? E/Vold? Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.apalon.weatherlive.free/cache/
04-23 13:31:39.320     829-1260/? E/WifiStateMachine? WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10022 txSuccessRate=11.27 rxSuccessRate=10.39 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-29
04-23 13:31:39.323     829-1260/? E/WifiStateMachine? [1,461,414,699,323 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{1000} uid 10022

15666-15666/? E/GMPM? GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

As you will see if you look at the code that follows, the key the error message quotes is there in the files.
Also, I do not understand the last message (above) about a missing resource.

I've just built the app ahain, this time in debug mode and it works absolutely fine, but what's interesting is I still get zillions of error messages, almost none of which make any sense to me.

I have compared the following files with the same files when built in debug mode and they appear to be identical. Any ideas on what I should do?  Thanks.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="owner.example.com.locator" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/earthicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDRtOnaTU1Jc-zxuirnbyNojZn9uasd7eE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LocateMe"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_locate_me" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Program File

```
package owner.example.com.locator;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
//import com.adjust.sdk.Adjust;
//import com.adjust.sdk.AdjustConfig;

public class LocateMe extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1340; // can be any code you want
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //String environment = AdjustConfig.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_me);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        AppData.locman = mLocationManager;
        //Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        //AppData.crit = criteria;
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Permission needed")
                            .setMessage("Sorry but we need permission to access your location")
                            .setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
                                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        AppData.loc = location;
        if (location != null) {
            LatLng myLastPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLastPosition));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

            for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getFL(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()) + "\n"
                                + BigDecimal.valueOf(AppData.loc.getLatitude()).setScale(5,
                                BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString() + "     "
                                + BigDecimal.valueOf(AppData.loc.getLongitude()).setScale(5,
                                BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };
        }
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, this);

        // Location button click listener will show Lat & Long when button clicked
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
            {
                try {
                    AppData.loc = AppData.locman.getLastKnownLocation(AppData.locman.getBestProvider
                            (criteria, false));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getFL(AppData.loc.getLatitude(), AppData.loc.getLongitude()) + "\n"
                                    + BigDecimal.valueOf(AppData.loc.getLatitude()).setScale(5,
                                    BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString() + "     "
                                    + BigDecimal.valueOf(AppData.loc.getLongitude()).setScale(5,
                                    BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "GPS Problem!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    // And the following method is courtesy of 'abi', a StackOverflow contributor from Dubai
    public static String getFL(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        try {
            int latSeconds = (int) Math.round(latitude * 3600);
            int latDegrees = latSeconds / 3600;
            latSeconds = Math.abs(latSeconds % 3600);
            int latMinutes = latSeconds / 60;
            latSeconds %= 60;

            int longSeconds = (int) Math.round(longitude * 3600);
            int longDegrees = longSeconds / 3600;
            longSeconds = Math.abs(longSeconds % 3600);
            int longMinutes = longSeconds / 60;
            longSeconds %= 60;
            String latDegree = latDegrees >= 0 ? "N" : "S";
            String lonDegree = longDegrees >= 0 ? "E" : "W";

            return Math.abs(latDegrees) + "° " + latMinutes + "' " + latSeconds
                    + "\"" + latDegree + "   " + Math.abs(longDegrees) + "° " + longMinutes
                    + "' " + longSeconds + "\"" + lonDegree;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return "" + String.format("%8.5f", latitude) + "\n"
                    + String.format("%8.5f", longitude);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng myLastPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLastPosition));
        float zoomvalue = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomvalue));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

google_maps_api.xml file

```
<resources>
<!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=6F:57:6E:22:FE:D8:BD:E9:C4:23:33:A9:1D:E5:C6:E9:6F:F8:5F:BD%3Bowner.example.com.locator

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
6F:57:6E:22:FE:D8:BD:E9:C4:23:33:A9:1D:E5:C6:E9:6F:F8:5F:BD;owner.example.com.locator

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
    AIzaSyDRtOnaTU1Jc-zxuirnbyNojZn9uasd7eE
</string>
</resources>
```

build.gradle (Module: app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'myreleasekey'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxxxx'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Owner/AndroidStudioProjects/release.jks')
        storePassword 'xxxxxxxx'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "owner.example.com.locator"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need a release key. For Google Maps API v2 you need a SHA-1 fingerprint. So:

- Create your app's release certificate using keytool
- Get the SHA-1 fingerprint from the release certificate again using keytool;
- Create your release API key and add your SHA-1 to it.

All this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#overview)

Comment: Thanks Iain, but doesn't the stuff in the build.gradle file show I already have an API key? I thought I'd followed the procedure exactly but must admit to not fully understanding the process. Are you suggesting I start over?

Comment: John that API key you have added previously was made from debug SHA-1 which is used in development environment. For release purpose, as @lain said, you need the API key made from SHA-1 of release key.

Comment: Yes thanks. Sorry Iain, just seen your final question!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the SHA keys, you should enable Maps API access in your [Google  account](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?filter=category:maps). Click "Google Maps Android API" then click "Enable".